# Solve system of differential equations and show the chaotic behavior of the solutions

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I want to solve a system of differential equations and show the chaotic behavior of the solutions. Here `x[t]`, `y[t]` and `z[t]` denotes the number of susceptibles, infectives, and AIDS-infected in a population, respectively.

```
{x'[t] == 45 - 0.0005 x[t] y[t] - 0.0743 x[t],
y'[t] == 0.0005 x[t] y[t] - 0.34 y[t], 
z'[t] == 0.023 y[t] - 0.5 z[t],
x[0] == 200, y[0] == 75, z[0] == 25.}
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory Tour now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: There is an expression in English: "I want" doesn't get. What have you tried? I suppose @Ivan's kind answer addressed your question, but please bear this in mind for the next one.

Answer (score 1):

This may help

```
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == 45 - 0.0005 x[t] y[t] - 0.0743 x[t], 
               y'[t] == 0.0005 x[t] y[t] - 0.34 y[t], 
               z'[t] == 0.023 y[t] - 0.5 z[t],
               x[0] == 200, y[0] == 75, z[0] == 25.},
        {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 20}];

Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 20}, PlotLegends -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image]